# How do I pass information from a servlet to a JSP page

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, servlets

Is it possible to have a servlet that contains an object (an ArrayList in this case) that then does the equivalent of displaying a jsp page and passing that object to the jsp page. In this case the ArrayList contains database results an I want to iterate through and display the results on the JSP page.

I am not using any MVC framework, is it possible to do this with the basic Servlet/JSP architecture.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

1. in the servlet call `request.setAttribute("result", yourArrayList);`
2. then forward to the jsp:

   ```
   getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("your.jsp")
       .forward(request, response);
   ```
3. using JSTL, in the jsp:

   ```
   <c:forEach items="${result}" var="item">
     ...
   </c:forEach>
   ```

If you don't want to use JSTL (but I recommend using it), then you can get the value using `request.getAttribute("result")` in the JSP as well.

Alternatively, but not recommended, you can use `request.getSession().setAttribute(..)` instead, if you want to `redirect()` rather than `forward()`.

Comment: Note that the reason for the redirect() approach not being recommended, is because you tell the browser to go to a new URL causing a new request where the "request" scope is different, hence the result cannot be stored in "request"-scope (request.setAttribute...) but must be stored in a scope available to a new request.  In standard JSP there is only the session scope available where objects live forever which is usually not desired.    I believe MyFaces Orchestra has an interesting alternative - http://myfaces.apache.org/orchestra/myfaces-orchestra-core/installation.html

Comment: yes, but that's too much, since he doesn't want to use an mvc framework

Answer (score 2):

You can pass objects to jsp's by embedding them within the Request.

`request.setAttribute("object", object);`

and within the jsp:

`request.getAttribute("object");`

Comment: What should I google to get more info, I don't seem to get anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can put it using request.setAttribute("myobj", myObj); see [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to make some kind of "component" then it's better to convert the JSP page into a custom tag. Here is excellent article about that: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/05/12/jsp2part4.html

Comment: Thanks, I actually do that now. It's much neater.