# How to get css formatting from JSP to a Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP file that refers to CSS. My JSP has a form that redirects to the servlet .

The servlet does some heavy database queries etc.

Then the data is shown on the servlet page

However since the servlet does not have any formatting , the data is displayed without any formatting . How can I get the formatting from that jsp file and apply it to servlet .

I could use

`out.println(".. )`

but this is not convinient.

Comment: ... Forward to a JSP page that displays the results?

Comment: Thank you for reply . So my servlet test.java should have some code that forwards data to the original jsp ? So my servlet becomes a simple class right ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: @Buras More or less, but what Chris says is correct; if this is a form submission then you should use the post-redirect-get pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:
1) put the content you want to show in a request scope. You can do this using `setAttribute()` of `request`. Eg, `request.setAttribute("mycontent", <your actual content>)`

2) "your actual content" can be any data structure. Choose one that fits your needs.

3) In your second JSP, use this data structure. YOu can do, `request.getAttribute("mycontent")` (dont forget the cast. This returns Object)

4) You can apply whatever CSS you have to this content.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Create another JSP page to which this servlet dispatches response, add your CSS there, use the JSP to render pages the way you want.

I suggest you go through MVC pattern for creating your web application.

[see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261420/how-do-i-pass-information-from-a-servlet-to-a-jsp-page?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't just have the servlet forward to the JSP.  Since the last action known to the browser is the post from the form, a refresh of the page to which you were forwarded causes another post to happen.  You probably don't want that.

The correct approach is to post to a servlet which performs the update logic.  The servlet then does a send-redirect (status 302?) back to the browser with the url of the follow-on page.  The browser then does a get for that page and a subsequent refresh will work correctly.