# Java EE, JSP - How to view exception on JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp, exception

I have code:

PersonServlet.java

```
try {
         personDao.addPerson(person);
         } catch (EJBException e) {
         String error = "Error";
         }
```

How can display error variable on JSP page? Can I display error message without using variable and java code in *.jsp file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass information from a servlet to a JSP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261420/how-do-i-pass-information-from-a-servlet-to-a-jsp-page)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isErrorPage` and `errorPage` attribute of page directive.

You should declare like :

```
<%@ page errorPage="exception.jsp" %>
```

in the jsp page from where there is chance of throwing exception. exception.jsp will show the error.

And declare like :

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
```

in **exception.jsp**.

In addition, if you want to show the error message in **exception.jsp** , add following lines :

```
<li><%=exception.getClass() %></li>
<li><%=exception.getMessage() %></li>
```

Where `exception` is the implicit object

Comment: Thanks, how can I show exception message in this same page where exception was throwed? (without redirect to exception.jsp) ?